# case statement trying to aggregate data in case statement using aggregate functions

Tags: sql, oracle

```
  SELECT c.DESCRIPTION,
         fobt.OBJECT_ID,
         fobt.FA_OBJECT_TRANS_VALUE_TYPE,
         fobt.OBJECT_TRANSACTION_ID,
         fobt.OBJECT_TRANSACTION_DATE,
         fobt.AMOUNT,
         fobt.FA_YEAR,
         fobt.FA_PERIOD,
         SUM(fobt.AMOUNT) OVER(
                                PARTITION BY fobt.
                                ORDER BY fobt., fobt.OBJECT_TRANSACTION_DATE
                              ) AS RUNTOTAL,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER(
                           PARTITION BY fobt.OBJECT_ID
                           ORDER BY fobt.FA_YEAR DESC
                          ) RK1,
         DENSE_RANK()
             OVER(
                  PARTITION BY fobt.OBJECT_ID, c.DESCRIPTION
                  ORDER BY
                      fobt.FA_YEAR,
                      fobt.FA_PERIOD,
                      c.DESCRIPTION DESC
                 )
             rnk2
    FROM FA_OBJECT_TRANSACTION fobt
         INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT COMPANY,
                                     OBJECT_ID,
                                     OBJECT_TRANSACTION_ID,
                                     CODE_C
                       FROM FA_) FT
             ON     fobt. = FT.
                AND fobt. = FT.OBJECT_TRANSACTION_ID
         INNER JOIN CODE_C c
             ON     FT.CODE_C = c.CODE_C
                AND FT.COMPANY = c.COMPANY
   WHERE     fobt.OBJECT_ID = 12345
         AND fobt.FA_ IN ('Depreciation')
ORDER BY 2, 4
```

I'm trying to fix the DENSE_RANK for OBJECT_ID, DESCRIPTION, YEAR AND PERIOD. There is only one object id = 1234 but there are 2 locations (Rotterdam and South Windsor).  Equipment A was logged in location South Windsor  from 5/2015 to 3/2016  and then transferred to Rotterdam on 4/2016. I will like to have a DENSE_RANK by PARTITION by OBJECT_ID and LOCATION but the order by is not working properly.  I would like to take the latest date(year and month by location of that piece of equipment.  For example, Equipment A on 3/2016 at location South Windsor would be ranked 1 because it is the latest date at that location and then transferred to location Rotterdam on 4/2016 and that would also get tagged ranked 1 because it changed location.  Below are the current results and second example is the desired result.

Comment: DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY fobt.OBJECT_ID,c.DESCRIPTION ORDER BY fobt.FA_YEAR,fobt.FA_PERIOD,c.DESCRIPTION desc)

Comment: Edit your question with the full code please Jedip.  you are showing a tiny snippet and it's hard to tell whats going on from there (if you show fobt.FA_Year, at least show what fobt. is in the from statement).  You will get much better help that way.

Comment: I just hosted up query as image.

Comment: Why image? Images are not welcome here, please post the code as formatted text

Comment: Heh, I didn't mean delete the question and the current/expected output with the edit...just include the text (not image please, we can't copy and paste to our test environments from images) along with the rest of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood everything correctly You need to add only `DESC` after `fa_year` in last `dense_rank`:

```
... dense_rank() over(partition by object_id, description 
                          order by fa_year desc, fa_period desc) as rk2
```

Alternatively use `over (... order by transaction_id desc)`.

Test:

```
with t (DESCRIPTION, OBJECT_ID, transaction_id, AMOUNT, FA_YEAR, FA_PERIOD)
       as (select 'South Windsor, CT', 22208, 278620, 257, 2015,  5 from dual union all
           select 'South Windsor, CT', 22208, 287864, 257, 2015,  6 from dual union all
           select 'South Windsor, CT', 22208, 305508, 257, 2015,  7 from dual union all
           select 'South Windsor, CT', 22208, 322323, 257, 2015,  8 from dual union all
           select 'South Windsor, CT', 22208, 330902, 257, 2015,  9 from dual union all
           select 'South Windsor, CT', 22208, 340183, 257, 2015, 10 from dual union all
           select 'South Windsor, CT', 22208, 350218, 257, 2015, 11 from dual union all
           select 'South Windsor, CT', 22208, 359261, 257, 2015, 12 from dual union all
           select 'South Windsor, CT', 22208, 374836, 257, 2016,  1 from dual union all
           select 'South Windsor, CT', 22208, 382864, 257, 2016,  2 from dual union all
           select 'South Windsor, CT', 22208, 388910, 257, 2016,  3 from dual union all
           select 'Rotterdam, NY',     22208, 388915, 257, 2016,  4 from dual)
select description, transaction_id, fa_year, fa_period, 
       sum(amount) over (partition by object_id order by fa_year, fa_period) total,
       dense_rank() over(partition by object_id order by fa_year desc) rk1,
       dense_rank() over(partition by object_id, description 
                             order by fa_year desc, fa_period desc) rk2
  from t
  order by object_id, transaction_id
```

Output:

```
DESCRIPTION       TRANSACTION_ID    FA_YEAR  FA_PERIOD      TOTAL    RK1    RK2
----------------- -------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------ ------
South Windsor, CT         278620       2015          5        257      2     11
South Windsor, CT         287864       2015          6        514      2     10
South Windsor, CT         305508       2015          7        771      2      9
South Windsor, CT         322323       2015          8       1028      2      8
South Windsor, CT         330902       2015          9       1285      2      7
South Windsor, CT         340183       2015         10       1542      2      6
South Windsor, CT         350218       2015         11       1799      2      5
South Windsor, CT         359261       2015         12       2056      2      4
South Windsor, CT         374836       2016          1       2313      1      3
South Windsor, CT         382864       2016          2       2570      1      2
South Windsor, CT         388910       2016          3       2827      1      1
Rotterdam, NY             388915       2016          4       3084      1      1
```

Comment: Thank you Ponder.  You answered my question.